# Can't install psycopg2

Tags: windows, installation, command-line, linker, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 so I can use PostgreSQL in Python and Django. I have run into multiple errors in the last few hours trying to install it, and can't seem to solve the latest one. When I run:

```
setup.py install
```

on the psycopg2 in the command console it attempts to install it, but then gives an error when trying to execute `link.exe` in the Visual Studio 8 folder.

This doesn't make sense to me, considering I got that executable to work when I launch it from Windows Explorer, and from the command console. I even made an environment variable for it. However, it keeps giving:

```
"error: command C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\link.exe" failed with exit status 1120
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out this 3 and a half hour process I've been going through was unecessary. an exe installer of psycopg2 can be downloaded from [here](http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/)

Answer (score 11):

In case anyone goes down this rabbit hole also, make sure your pip is up-to-date:

```
$ pip install -U pip
$ pip install psycopg2-binary
```

See: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html.

That's 3 hours of my life I won't get back.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.

[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KIlb.png)

first run
`sudo apt install libpq-dev python3-dev`

then
`pip3 install psycopg2`

Comment: This helps in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS fresh install. Thank you @Vitória !

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2.

In release history select the version you want to download: there will be a table with files and compatible versions of Python.

Download the binary file that matches your system configuration.

For example, for Python 3.6 on Windows 10 (64-bit) download `psycopg2-2.8.6-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`.