# Python psycopg2-2.5.1 installation on Windows 8

Tags: python, postgresql, mingw32

I am installing Python psycopg2 , its compilation fails: 
 OS: Windows 8 64 bit 
 Python: 2.7 
 mingw-w64

```
C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-4.9.0-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev2/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64
-mingw32/4.9.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'C:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-4.9.0-win32-seh-rt_v3-rev2\\mingw64\\bin\\
gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: You might want to install a [binary distribution of psycopg2 for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg).

Answer (score 2):

> cannot find -lpython27

`python27.lib` is not on your `LIBRARY_PATH`. It's hard to say why or provide more info because you didn't explain how you got to this point - commands run, Python version installed, etc.

In any case, I strongly recommend that you [just use the binary installers](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg). See these existing answers:

- [Install psycopg2 on Windows 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22754097/398670)
- [How to easy_install psycopg2 on windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24119073/398670)
- [How to install psycopg2 with "pip" on Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5420789/398670)
- [installing psycopg2 on Windows xp using pip and virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17496927/398670)
- [Can't install psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16629081/398670)